# On Polling Unable to receive response from IBM MQ Server

Tags: c++, websphere, ibm-mq, polling, tcpsocket

Hi I am working on an application that sends message to IBM WebSphere MQ and receives response.
There at 2 queues at WebSphere end, 1 for receiving message from my MQ client application and other one sends back response accordingly.

Previously it was working fine as TCP communication between WebSphere MQ and MQ client was implemented using sockets but now I have implemented polling and since then message sending MQ client to WebSphere gets successful and it can be seen in the receiving queue but when I put response message in sending queue at WebSphere end it keeps stuck there.

My MQ client application keeps polling and when I put response message in sender IBM MQ It doesn't receive at MQ client end, when I change back polling based communication to socket based all the stuck messages in WebSphere sender queue gets received at My MQ client application end.

I have tried many things but no success till now kindly specify what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Did you commit your message? Please show us your code so we can help you debug.

Comment: What do you mean by socket vs polling?  And +1 on making sure you commit your message.